# Get byte size of List<T>

Tags: .net, winforms, list, byte

Silly question, but in a winforms app Im currently working on, I would like to get the amount of bytes allocated/used by a `List<[SomeObject]>` held in memory (for statistical purposes).  Is this possible?  I have searched thru the possible options, but there is obviously no `myList.GetTotalBytes()` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure the runtime provides a reliable programmatic method of getting an object's size, however there are some options open to you:

- use a tool like CLR Profiler
- use [Marshal.SizeOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx) (returns the unmanaged size of the object)
- serialize your object to binary for an approximation

Comment: woah, that was quick! thanks 4 the reply! unfortunately, I am looking for a method available at runtime, and hopefully not something that will involve me tearing the list apart and iterating thru each object.

Comment: missed the mention of the CLR Profiler. Never used it before, but thanks for that - im gonna go read up a bit more on using it!

Answer (score 13):

It really depends on what you mean. You can predict how many bytes will be used by the list itself - but that's not the same as predicting how many bytes might be eligible for garbage collection if the list became eligible for collection.

Bits of the list:

- The backing array (`T[]` - a reference to an array that only the list will have access to)
- The size (int)
- A sync root (reference)
- The version number (int)

The tricky bit is deciding how much to count. Each of those is fairly easy to calculate (particularly if you know that T is a reference type, for example) but do you want to count the objects *referenced* by the list? Are those references the only ones, or not?

You say you want to know "for statistical purposes" - could you be more precise? If you can say what you're really interested in (and a bit more information about what's in the list and whether there may be other references to the same objects) we could probably help more.

Comment: Hi Jon, and thanx 4the reply. sorry 4 not being very clear.  The List is a collection of Table Entities being populated from a LINQ query.  And this one contains mainly string and dateTime types.

Comment: "for statistical purposes" - lets say my query yields a collection containing 10,000 Entity objects, and (assuming I can calculate this better) each object occupies on avg 25 bytes of memory, I would like to get the cumulative bytes total of all Entity objects in the List

Comment: As mentioned before, I am looking for an alternative to iterating thru the objects and drilling down to each property, as also mentioned by Jan

Comment: So you want to actually include all the elements of the list, and you're going to assume that nothing else has a reference? There's really no way of getting that information I'm afraid.

Answer (score 12):

This may be a full-of-horse-pucky answer, but I'm going to go out on a limb and say if you're doing statistical comparisons, do a binary serialize of the object to a `MemoryStream` and then look at its `Length` property as such:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>
    {
        "This",
        "is",
        "a",
        "test"
    };

    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, list);
        Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
    }
```

Take note that this could change between different versions of the framework and would only be useful for comparisons between object graphs within a single program.

Comment: Must not forget using [Serializable] for strongly typed objects